# How to pass parameterized values in Jenkins's Execute Shell using echo?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, continuous-integration, command-line-interface, cypress

I'm running [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) test suites using [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/). I have created `Execute shell` scripts that run the entire suite & it's working nicely like so:

```sh
cd frontend
node --version
yarn install
echo '{ "USERNAME": "redacted-harcoded-username", "PASSWORD": "redacted-harcoded-password", BASE_URL: "redacted-harcoded-baseURl" }' > cypress.env.json
yarn cypress:run
```

However, I passed some Jenkins's parameters like so:

```sh
cd frontend
node --version
yarn install
echo `{ "USERNAME": ${USERNAME}, "PASSWORD": ${PASSWORD}, BASE_URL: ${BASE_URL} }` > cypress.env.json
yarn cypress:run --spec ${SPECS_TO_RUN}
```

Unfortunately, when using `echo` I need to switch the single quotes to be able to pass the dynamic values like so:

```sh
echo `{ "USERNAME": ${USERNAME}, "PASSWORD": ${PASSWORD}, BASE_URL: ${BASE_URL} }` > cypress.env.json
```

This is causing my command to fail & give me an error that my `json` file is not valid. Any workarounds to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you try with `echo \`{ "USERNAME": "${USERNAME}", "PASSWORD": "${PASSWORD}", BASE_URL: ${BASE_URL} }\`` ?

Comment: @LajosArpad I get this error: `Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "}")`

Comment: How about `echo \`{ "USERNAME": "${USERNAME}", "PASSWORD": "${PASSWORD}", BASE_URL: "${BASE_URL}" }\``? Do you still get an error?

Comment: Yeah, it 's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution with this combination of bash escaping:

```sh
echo { \"USERNAME\": \"${USERNAME}\", \"PASSWORD\": \"${PASSWORD}\", \"BASE_URL\": \"${BASE_URL}\"  } > cypress.env.json
```